# How to get the link if url contain Chinese by swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, hyperlink, attributes

I have a string of link, but it contains the Chinese.
And then my app will crash.
How to prevent whether url contains Chinese or not, it can show the link normally  .

```
var youTextLabel = UILabel()
var message = "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/斯蒂芬·科里"

let linkAttributes = [NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: message)!, //This get error!!
                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue,
                  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue] as [String : Any]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)
let urlCharacterCount = message.characters.count
attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, urlCharacterCount))
youTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Do you need the information on Chinese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you are trying to use needs to be properly encoded. One solution is to build the URL using `URLComponents`.

```
var root = "https://zh.wikipedia.org"
var path = "/wiki/斯蒂芬·科里"
var urlcomps = URLComponents(string: root)!
urlcomps.path = path
let url = urlcomps.url!
print(url)
```

Output:

> https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%AF%E8%92%82%E8%8A%AC%C2%B7%E7%A7%91%E9%87%8C

Answer (score 8):

Try percent escape your url string:

```
var message = "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/斯蒂芬·科里".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Output:

> "https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%AF%E8%92%82%E8%8A%AC%C2%B7%E7%A7%91%E9%87%8C"

Comment: editted, `urlQueryAllowed` will give correct answer